# What to do when Micro-service doesn't respond

Tags: java, maven, microservices

Right now I have a micro-service which has 3-4 API's in it and always logs every minute. At some point, it just stops logging and none of APIs works . It just doesn't respond. I'am sorry cause I don't have lot information to explain.

Comment: Have you monitored the JVM with something like Jvisualvm?

Comment: how are  you logging in your micro services?

Comment: @JFMeier I will try with what you have suggested

Comment: @SujayMohan normal docker logs , Log4j to be exact.

Comment: First step is to obtain thread dump

Comment: Please add what technology language you have devloped microservice , where you deployed  if have any code sample to get quick and correct ans

Comment: @vaquarkhan this microservice is purely java .

Comment: @rkosegi I'am trying to get the tread dump , but this situations arises after 2-3 days of continuous usage.